# Juego de cartas en C# para GUI

Tags: c#, interfaz-gráfica

Hice este juego de cartas en GUI, donde Hay 52 cartas en una baraja. 1-10, jota, reina, rey, as (el as es la carta más alta).

Es un juego de 2 jugadores, cada jugador comienza con 26 cartas (la mitad del mazo),El juego comienza con cada jugador volteando 1 carta y el que tenga la carta más alta gana. El ganador recibe la tarjeta de otros jugadores. Si hay un empate, las siguientes tres cartas de tu mazo se juegan boca abajo y la cuarta carta se reparte boca arriba, gana el que tenga la carta más alta. El ganador recibe todas las cartas jugadas. El juego se juega hasta que 1 jugador tiene toda la tarjeta.

Pero, no se por que no funciona a pesar de que aparentemente todo esta correcto. Alguna idea o consejo? Gracias

```
namespace Wargame2
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        class Card
        {
            public string Name;
            public int Value;
            public string Suit;
            public override string ToString() { return string.Format("{0} of {1}", Name, Suit); }

        }
        class DeckOfCards
        {

            public List<Card> DeckOfCard {get; set;}=new List<Card>
                {
                 
                    new Card{Name="two",Value=2,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card{Name="three",Value=3,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card{Name="four",Value=4,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card{Name="five", Value=5, Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card{Name="six",Value=6,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card{Name="seven",Value=7,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card{Name="eight",Value=8,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card { Name="Nine", Value=9, Suit="heart"},
                    new Card{Name="ten",Value=10,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card{Name="jack",Value=11,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card{Name="queen",Value=12,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card { Name="king", Value=13, Suit="heart"},
                    new Card { Name="Ace", Value=14, Suit="Heart"},


                    new Card{Name="two",Value=2,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card{Name="three",Value=3,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card{Name="four",Value=4,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card { Name="five", Value=5, Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card{Name="six",Value=6,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card{Name="seven",Value=7,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card{Name="eight",Value=8,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card { Name="Nine", Value=9, Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card{Name="ten",Value=10,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card{Name="jack",Value=11,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card{Name="queen",Value=12,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card { Name="king", Value=13, Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card { Name="Ace", Value=14, Suit="Spades"},


                    new Card{Name="two",Value=2,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card{Name="three",Value=3,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card{Name="four",Value=4,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card { Name="five", Value=5, Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card{Name="six",Value=6,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card{Name="seven",Value=7,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card{Name="eight",Value=8,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card { Name="Nine", Value=9, Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card{Name="ten",Value=10,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card{Name="jack",Value=11,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card{Name="queen",Value=12,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card { Name="king", Value=13, Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card { Name="Ace", Value=14, Suit="Diamonds"},

                    new Card{Name="two",Value=2,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card{Name="three",Value=3,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card{Name="four",Value=4,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card { Name="five", Value=5, Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card{Name="six",Value=6,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card{Name="seven",Value=7,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card{Name="eight",Value=8,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card { Name="Nine", Value=9, Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card{Name="ten",Value=10,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card{Name="jack",Value=11,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card{Name="queen",Value=12,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card { Name="king", Value=13, Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card { Name="Ace", Value=14, Suit="Clubs"},

             };
        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = ("Each player is flipping over 1 card and whomever has the highest card wins");

            DeckOfCards DeckOfCard2 = new  DeckOfCards();
            var test = DeckOfCard2.DeckOfCard;
            List<Card> deckOfPlayer1 = new List<Card>();
            List<Card> deckOfPlayer2 = new List<Card>();

            Random random = new Random();
            int player1 = random.Next();
            int player2 = random.Next();

            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            {
                deckOfPlayer1.Add(DeckOfCard2.DeckOfCard[random.Next(26)]);
                deckOfPlayer2.Add(DeckOfCard2.DeckOfCard[random.Next(26)]);

                label1.Text = ($"Player1 has {deckOfPlayer1[i]} and " + ($"Player2 has {deckOfPlayer2[i]}"));
                label2.Text = ($"Player2 has {deckOfPlayer2.Count}  cards" + ($"Player2 has {deckOfPlayer2.Count} cards"));

            }


            do
            {

                // pick a random card for player 1
                int r1;
                r1 = random.Next(0, 1);
                Card c1 = deckOfPlayer1[r1];
                deckOfPlayer1.Add(c1);
                deckOfPlayer1.RemoveAt(r1);


                // pick a random card for player 2
                int r2;
                r2 = random.Next(0, 1);
                Card c2 = deckOfPlayer2[r2];
                deckOfPlayer2.Add(c2);
                deckOfPlayer2.RemoveAt(r2);

                label1.Text = ($"Player1 has {c1} and" + ("Player2 has: {0}", c2));

                label1.Text = ($"Player1 has {deckOfPlayer1.Count} cards" + ($"Player2 has {deckOfPlayer2.Count} +cards"));


                // now compare the cards
                if (c1.Value > c2.Value)
                {

                    label1.Text = ("Player1 wins");
                    deckOfPlayer1.Add(c2);
                    deckOfPlayer2.Remove(c2);
                }
                else if (c2.Value > c1.Value)
                {
                    label2.Text = ("Player2 wins");
                    deckOfPlayer2.Add(c1);
                    deckOfPlayer1.Remove(c1);
                }

                if (c2.Value == c1.Value)
                {

                    label1.Text = ("Its a tie! Next three cards in deck are played face down, " +
                        "4th card face up, whoever has the highest card wins");

                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                    {


                        label1.Text = ($"Player1 has {deckOfPlayer1[0].Name}{deckOfPlayer1[0].Suit} {deckOfPlayer1[0].Value}");
                        label2.Text = ($"Player2 has {deckOfPlayer2[0].Name}{deckOfPlayer2[0].Suit} {deckOfPlayer2[0].Value}");

                    }

                    if (deckOfPlayer1[4].Value > deckOfPlayer2[4].Value)
                    {

                        label1.Text = ("Player1 wins");
                        deckOfPlayer1.Add(c2);
                        deckOfPlayer2.Remove(c2);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        label2.Text = ("Player2 wins");
                        deckOfPlayer2.Add(c1);
                        deckOfPlayer1.Remove(c1);
                    }

                }



            } while (deckOfPlayer1.Count < 52 || (deckOfPlayer2.Count < 52));

        }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! "Pero, no se por que no funciona a pesar de que aparentemente todo esta correcto".. nosotros tampoco sabemos que quiere decir que no funciona... por favor, especifica el problema.. no ejecuta? tira un error? no termina nunca? no muestra al ganador? no reparte las cartas? que quiere decir no funciona? usa el boton [edit] y aclara el problema...

Comment: pero que es lo que no funciona?

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Buenas, PERDON, por favor, soy nuevo en este mundo de programacion, el problema es que cuando doy la tecla de ejecucion, me pone este letrero "Exception user unhandled
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')'"